# how to change softmaxlayer with regression in matconvnet

Tags: regression, deep-learning, mnist, loss, matconvnet

I am trying to train MNIST data set with single output. It means when i give an 28*28 input (image) the model gives us a just number. For example i give '5', the model give me as a result 4.9,5, 5.002 or close to 5. So I have red some documents. People tells softmaxlayer have to be changed with regression layer. For doing do this. I am using matconvnet library and its mnist example. I have changed my network and written regression layer loss function. these are my codes:

```
net.layers = {} ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{f*randn(5,5,1,20, 'single'), zeros(1, 20, 'single')}}, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'pool', ...
                           'method', 'max', ...
                           'pool', [2 2], ...
                           'stride', 2, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{f*randn(5,5,20,50, 'single'),zeros(1,50,'single')}}, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'pool', ...
                           'method', 'max', ...
                           'pool', [2 2], ...
                           'stride', 2, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{f*randn(4,4,50,500, 'single'),  zeros(1,500,'single')}}, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu') ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{f*randn(1,1,500,1, 'single'), zeros(1,1,'single')}}, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;                         
 net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'normloss');
```

this is regression loss function:

```
function Y = vl_normloss(X,c,dzdy)
size(X)%1 1 1 100
size(c)%1 100

if nargin <= 2

Y = 0.5*sum((squeeze(X)'-c).^2);
size(Y)%1 1
Y      % 1.7361e+03
else
size(Y)
Y = +((squeeze(X)'-c))*dzdy;
Y = reshape(Y,size(X));
end
```

I changed `opts.errorFunction = 'multiclass' ;` to `'none'` 
Also i add

```
case 'normloss'
      res(i+1).x = vl_normloss(res(i).x,l.class) ;
```

to vl_simplenn script

But when i run train this error occurs

> Error using vl_nnconv DEROUTPUT dimensions are incompatible with X and
>   FILTERS.
>
> Error in vl_simplenn (line 415)
>           [res(i).dzdx, dzdw{1}, dzdw{2}] = ...

what i have to do for solving this problem? thank you

Comment: > I am trying to train MNIST data set with single output
Don't do that. Using regression for classification tasks is a bad idea.

Comment: I know this is bad idea, but i have to do this

Comment: I did what you said, i mean i changed vl_simplenn and used norm loss as last layer, but still when i train the net, in the output, it says it's softmaxloss and it's not using normloss. do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Probably Softmaxloss has not been changed with normloss in your codes, you cna check your function names (normloss softmaxloss) in vl_simplenn script both feedforward and backward parts. Also check your cnn_init script. Your error looks simple but i dont know exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have made a mistake. There are 2 different line have to be changed in vl_simplenn script but i changed only one line. This code works.

Answer (score 0):

I've a question.

```
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'weights', {{f*randn(1,1,500,1, 'single'), zeros(1,1,'single')}}, ...
                           'stride', 1, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;                         
 net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'normloss');
```

In conv layer the output [1 1 500 1] shows a descriptor of 1x500? In the loss layer how you using that value? Shouldn't the loss layer softmax predict the class prob and then you find the highest prob corresponding class? Or in this case the output of [1 1 500 1] is the probability?

Comment: This looks like a comment to the question instead of an answer. If you intend to comment, you need to have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Normloss layer isn't similir to softmax, I mean that normloss doesn't predict any class using highest probability. It just find a value. This value isn't class prob. Also in last layer, 500 inputs goes to only 1 output. So we get only one output.

Comment: So what is the value from the fc [1 1 500 1] is being used for normloss? I mean its a feature vector 1x500. In the normloss there is a calculation (input-GroundTruth). But groundtruth, e.g. 5 , is subtracted form what? This is doing regression right?